# Naming advice for a start-up

Tags: geography

I'm preparing to open up a start-up. Because of some personal reasons, I'd like to name it after the small town in China I was born in. It's named 下关 (dry translate to down-gate or down-fort).

That name came after its geography situation. 大理 (Dali) is an old city located in a valley and it has 2 major entrances/exits. People in old Dali built a fort on each of the entrances. The north one called 上关 (up-gate) and the south one called 下关 (down-gate).

I believe this kind of geography is common around the world, I'm hoping there are authentic English words that can describe it beautifully. Please share your knowledge.

Comment: The question  is a little unclear, but to a New Yorker it sounds a bit  like "uptown" and "downtown"..

Comment: Hello, StanleyZ. This is an interesting question--makes me sorry that names are [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here--, but you could consider [lowgap](https://goo.gl/maps/9v5wWE1p7K46frw96) and [lowgate](https://goo.gl/maps/NvqWZv4dEtjbrJoFA) as approximate equivalents already used (beautifully, I may say) in English-speaking geographical names. Please give some time to the [tour] if you haven't. Welcome to ELU, cheers!

Comment: Hi @Conrado, thanks for pointing it out. I'm sorry I missed that part, I will go through them again.

Comment: Northgate and Southgate are also pretty common names for things like subdivisions (housing tracts) and shopping malls.

Comment: @ThePhoton I like Southgate, it reminds me of London. I definitely will put it into my shortlist.

Comment: Are you focusing exclusively on the fixed idea of naming the firm after something important to you and not your customers? Caution: That can freeze the business and artistic drive.

Comment: @YosefBaskin thanks for your thought. I didn't mention it because I thought it's not relevant. this firm is a holding company for investments (like stocks). It's usual that people name this kind with a city / county name, e.g. berkshire / Brookfield. I think it should be ok.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as a general rule naming things is off-topic.